# TeamCity, NodeJS and API testing

Tags: node.js, express, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm setting up CI/CD which includes TeamCity as build server.
I have set up 3 build steps:

1. npm install,
2. node server.js,
3. node run_tests.js

My `server.js` file runs a REST API via EXPRESS --> which I realized blocks TeamCity in running step #3...which I now understand why...(because everything is run by the same "window" when TeamCity executes it - because it doesn't not exit again...but keeps listening as expected of an API).

How do I run the API, call it and test/confirm it works, shut it down again and then continue with the next step...?

Comment: yes, you need to down step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

1. Start the app/API via PM2
2. Execute tests which uses the API
3. Stop the app/API via PM2

:-)